# Can a set of commutation relations be overdetermined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider a set of matrix commutation relations $\{[M_i,M_j]=0\}$. Could I infer new commutation relations between the $M_i$'s that are not given by this set of relations ? Or does this set of relations always totally determines all the possible commuting pairs $(M_i,M_j)$ ? In other words, are some sets of commutation relations compressible into a smaller number of commutation relations ?

Comment: I think the answer is negative. Consider the case where $[A_1,A_2]\ne0$ and $A_3=A_4=\cdots=A_n=0$. Then all but one of the $\binom{n}{2}$ commutators $[A_i,A_j]$ are zero but the remaining one is not.

Comment: You can deduce things like $M_i^2,M_j]=0$ and $[M_i+M_j,M_k]=0$.

Comment: Sorry, left out a bracket. That first example was meant to be $[M_i^2,M_j]=0$.